# Select rows in the bottom of the Grid and problem is moved to the top

Tags: c#, winforms, scroll, telerik-grid, radgridview

My problem is when I select  many rows in `radGridView` (Telerik) and especially when I select rows in the bottom of the `RadGridView`. the scroll move to the top. 
I need to fix the scroll position to be in the same position of the last selected row.

Thank you.

This is my code :

```
private void radGVToBeApproved_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.radGVToBeApproved.SummaryRowsTop.Clear();
    this.radGVToBeApproved.SummaryRowsBottom.Clear();

    GridViewSummaryItem summaryItemCount = 
        new GridViewSummaryItem(radGVToBeApproved.Columns[0].Name, "Total rows : {0}", GridAggregateFunction.Count);
    GridViewSummaryItem summaryItemSelectedRowsCount = 
        new GridViewSummaryItem(radGVToBeApproved.Columns[0].Name, "    Total selected rows : {0}", 

    radGVToBeApproved.SelectedRows.Count.ToString());

    GridViewSummaryRowItem summaryRowItem = 
        new GridViewSummaryRowItem(
            new GridViewSummaryItem[] { summaryItemCount, summaryItemSelectedRowsCount });

    this.radGVToBeApproved.SummaryRowsTop.Add(summaryRowItem);
    this.radGVToBeApproved.SummaryRowsBottom.Add(summaryRowItem);
}
```